# Matching a complicated route with a regular expression

Tags: php, regex, model-view-controller, url-routing, matching

I'm currently working on a request router for a large PHP based website that I'm working on, but I'm getting stuck trying to use a custom form of expression for my routes.

While I know there are pre-made alternatives and routers that could make my life easier, and would have the same features (in fact, I've been looking at their source code to try and solve this), I'm still a programming student and learning how to create my own can only be a good thing!

---

**Examples:**

Here's an example of one of my route expressions:

- `<protocol (https?)>://<wildcard>.example.com/<controller>/{<lang=en (en|de|pl)>/}<name ([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{8})>`

This could match either of these equally well:

- `http://www.example.com/test/en/hello_123`
- `https://subdomain.example.com/another_test/hello_45`

Returning me a nice, handy array like this (for the latter):

```
array(
    'protocol' => 'http',
    'wildcard' => 'subdomain',
    'controller' => 'another_test',
    'lang' => 'en',
    'name' => "hello_45"
)
```

I can also include an array in the first place, with default values that would be overridden by the values found by the router. So, for example, I could leave out the `<controller>` variable and just write `test` instead, and then use the array, adding `"controller"=>"test"`.

---

**Here's the rules:**

- If there's no match, there's no match. Variables have to exist, and if they don't, the route is skipped. Goodbye. Optional sections don't have to exist, luckily.
- Anything between `<>` is a variable. Escaped `\<\>` are ignored, even when between. The area matching in the URL should be saved to the result array, with the variable name as the key.
- Curly braces `{}` mark a section as optional, and can never be *inside* a variable `<>`. Anything between them can be ignored in the target - however, if there is a default value specified for any variables in between, that variable must be added to the result array, using the name as the key, and with the default value as the value. Escaped braces are ignored.
- A variable doesn't have to have a default value, but if you add one, it needs to be after an `=`, like `<name=default>`.
- Regex rules can be added, separated by a space after the name or default value, and encased in brackets `()`. Escaped brackets are ignored, of course.
- Lastly, you can just put Regex rules, in brackets, anywhere, if you don't mind matching anything and not getting a result. So, I could just replace `<controller>` with `([\/]+)`, but then I'd have to use the array to set a value for it instead.

---

**What I've Tried:**

I've been reading the source code of every Router I can find.

So far, I've done a couple of nasty little regular expressions, but I realised I was confused completely about how to conglomerate them and extend them.

- This matches the brackets, ignoring escaped ones: `{([^{\\]*(?:\\.[^}\\]*)*)}`
- This matches a variable, with or without the default value: `<([^<\\]*(?:\\.[^>\\]*)*)(?:=?([^<>\\]*))>`
- This is a kind of unholy hell, the like of which made me write this post: `<([^<\\]*(?:\\.[^>\\]*)*)(?:=?([^<>\\]*))(?: ?)(\([^{}<>\(\)\\]+\))?>`
  (It does, however, match the variables and the Regex sections.)

---

Can anybody give me any hints, or even example source code from libraries that offer similar functionality? And if this is really near impossible to code myself, is there a library good enough to use?

Comment: Just to clarify: Are you attempting to parse the route expression itself (`<protocol (https?)>://...`) which will be responsible for then parsing something else (like a URL)? Is this just to validate that there are no typos or other logical errors within the route expression?

Comment: Additionally, should the `{<lang=en (en|de|pl)>/}` contain that trailing '/' before the last `}` character?

Comment: Right, okay, the trailing slash isn't needed, it's optional. Anything can go there, or at the start.

And I'm trying to parse the expression itself - but I've been working on a solution myself which is looking promising, so I may just post my own as the answer and close this, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to match the domain, [this regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/uW5nJ7/1) should match those portions with the individual sections named.

On the other hand, if you are trying to match the route expression, [this other regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/jI3hS0/1) is able to parse the tokens you specified so far.

I may have missed some specifications, but you can always leave feedback and explain where it falls short (or even update the regex on that site itself and save a newer version).